# Copy first row of attributes and paste for each feature

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, combo-box, fields-attributes, unique-value

In a newly digitised polyline vector layer, there are 7 columns attributes value that are choosen inside a value map combo-box that MUST be exactly the same for every newly digitised line (I choose the values for the first digitised line then all the other newly digitised lines must have the same value of the first one).

I'd like to fill them (in a kind of automatic, or auto completed way) with the exact same values of the first digitised row.

I was thinking about some unique values properties, but since the values are kept inside a combobox I can't use both field properties together.
OR to complete the missing values with some field calculator expression at the end of the digiting.

EDIT:
I'm using QGIS 2.8 and 2.10 running in both Windows and Ubuntu 
I post a screenshot of the value map used for 7 different columns, all real(4,3)

[image]

The attribute table is the following one and all the "empty" () columns should have the same value appearing in the first row

[image]

Like this 
[image]

Comment: see if now it s clear to you

Comment: I tried to answer, but the more often I read the question, the more confused I am.

Comment: edited again, hope that now my qestion is understandable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you're asking for an answer related to value map combo-boxes, I thought to provide an alternative where you could use the following code to read the values in the first row for each column and copy it for each of the attributes. Select the layer in QGIS and copy/paste the code into the Python Console (`Plugins -> Python Console` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd>):

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
for field in layer.pendingFields():
    name = field.name()
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(0)
    feat = layer.getFeatures(request).next()
    result = feat[name]
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        feature[name] = result
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

This is not automated, which is what you seem to be asking for. But I hope it helps a little anyway! Tested this on QGIS 2.8.2-Wien.

---

**Update:**

If you want to run the above script in the graphical modeler, first select the **Create new script** tool from `Processing Toolbox -> Scripts`. Note you said 7 columns but gave 8 :). Then insert the following:

```py
##Copy attributes from first row=name
##Layer=vector

import qgis
from qgis.core import *

layer = processing.getObject(input)
layer.startEditing()
for field in layer.pendingFields():
        name = field.name()
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(0)
        feat = layer.getFeatures(request).next()
        result = feat[name]
        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
                if name == 'ALT_0':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
                if name == 'ALT_1':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
                if name == 'ALT_2':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
                if name == 'ALT_3':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
                if name == 'ALT_4':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
                if name == 'ALT_5':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
                if name == 'ALT_Ideale':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
                if name == 'ALT_propos':
                        feature[name] = result
                        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Also note that I purposely did not save the changes just incase there's a mistake. If you want the script to save the changes, use the `layer.commitChanges()` code at the end of the script outside all the `for` loops.

I tested this and it seems to work so hopefully it will for you too =)

Comment: Thank You! It's kind of what I was looking for, the only thing that I have to improve to your script is the fact that I need to update the values of only  7 columns (ALT_0, ALT_1, ALT_2, ALT_3, ALT_4, ALT_5, ALT_Ideale and ALT_propos) and not all the attributes of the layer. Can you help me to modify the script in order to do this?

Comment: And I have to put this script inside the graphical modeler, is there anything else I have to modify?

Comment: @Mattia - I edited my post, hopefully it will work for you :)

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you so much Joseph! I'll give a try inside the modeler in the next days.

Comment: @Mattia - Awesome buddy, glad it works :)

Comment: I'm trying to add the script at the beginning of my graphical model, but I have a little issue on that since the script you provided does not create an output layer I cannot use as input for the algorithms I have to run. I tried to add ##output_layer=output vector at the beginning of the script, now I see it in the windows but I think that something has to be defined inside the script to create the output vector. any advice?

Comment: @Mattia - I will see what I can do as the code I added does need some _cleaning_ up :)

Comment: @Mattia - I wrote a script which you can use as an output for the model builder although it copies the attributes of **all fields** in the first row (I'm unsure how to incorporate the `if` conditions in the script for your desired columns). If you're still interested then it may be best to post it as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as I think it's starting to deviate too much from your original question :)

Comment: Thank you anyway! I tough it was already clear in this question that I don't need to copy all the fields, but if you think that it will be better to post it as a new question i will do it, no problem!

Comment: new question here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159738/python-script-to-copy-first-row-of-certain-attributes-and-paste-in-the-newly-dig

Comment: @Mattia - You're right that you specified you don't need all fields in your question. But there's no mention of using the graphical modeler :).

Answer (score 2):

Joseph's answer worked perfectly for me as well ! However you have to adapt it a bit if you want to use it with QGIS 3.

In Python 3 `layer.getFeatures(request).next()` is deprecated and `next(layer.getFeatures(request))` shall be used instead ! :)

```
layer.startEditing()
for field in layer.fields():
    name = field.name()
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(0)
    feat = next(layer.getFeatures(request))
    result = feat[name]
```