# Python script to copy first row of certain attributes and paste in the newly digitised rows the copied features

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

Starting from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159400/copy-first-row-of-attributes-and-paste-for-each-feature/159443?noredirect=1#comment236561_159443), I need a script to be insterted in the processing graphical modeler that can copy some attributes from the first digitised row in all the newly digitised lines of a polyline vector layer. As said I don't need to copy all the attributes, just 8 attributes (column names are: `ALT_0`, `ALT_1`, `ALT_2`, `ALT_3`, `ALT_4`, `ALT_5`, `ALT_Ideale` and `ALT_propos`)

The script has to produce an output in order to be inserted in the next algorithms of my model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script (save it in *Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script*) in the graphical modeler to **copy the first row of attributes and apply it to each feature** in the input layer.

(*Unfortunately I was unable to add a filter for your required fields so hopefully others can provide a solution which completely answers your question*).

```
##Copy shapefile and first row attributes=name
##input=vector
##output=output vector

import qgis
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureRequest, QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry

layer = processing.getObject(input)
provider = layer.dataProvider()
fields = provider.fields()
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(output, 'UTF-8', fields, provider.geometryType(), layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")

feat = QgsFeature()
for field in layer.pendingFields():
    name = field.name()
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(0)
    feat = layer.getFeatures(request).next()
    result = feat[name]

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    feat.setGeometry(feature.geometry() )
    writer.addFeature(feat)

del writer
```

[image: Script in modeler]

Tested this with a simple point layer with the buffer tool and it worked so hopefully it will for you :)